# Azure B2C login problems

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c

I need to resolve the B2C login in a web application. I'm very new to B2C. The B2C token will contain the user information ? I can set it in the claims all the data that I need?

I must extend it from data from our DB, it is possible, too?

Comment: Can you add your use case in detail? that would help others to give more details.

Answer (score 1):

What specific issue are you running into? I can better diagnose your problem if you give me a bit more information.

If you follow the [official Microsoft guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-quickstarts-web-app) for ASP.NET web applications using B2C you can easily achieve B2C login. The guide comes with an accompanying Github sample that you can clone in order to achieve what you are looking for. [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-reference-tokens) you can also check out the B2C token reference page to see the contents of each type of token in B2C. You can use ID tokens to identify users in your app.

As for your second question, you can migrate data from your local database to Azure AD B2C but just cannot use Azure SQL. See this [migration guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-user-migration) to learn how to do this using Azure AD Graph API.